# Unable to increment an environment variable in tcl

Tags: tcl

I can read/set environment variables in my tcl script (The `ECO_FINISH` environment variable in the snippet below can be set and read properly), but I am unable to increment a set environment variable (`ECO_ITER`).

```
set ::env(ECO_ITER) 0

set   fp   [open  /home/khtaur/test.txt "r"]
set   fd   [read  $fp]
set   txt  [split $fd "\n"]
close $fp

# For each line in the read file
foreach line $txt {
    # Exit the loop if no violations are reported

    if {[regexp {No violations} $txt]} {
        set ::env(ECO_FINISH) 1
    } else {
        if {$::env(ECO_ITER) != 0} {
            # This will not increment
            set  ::env(ECO_ITER) [expr {$::env(ECO_ITER) + 1}]
            puts "$::env(ECO_ITER)" # This is 0
            # Do stuff
        } else {
            # Ans so is this
            set  ::env(ECO_ITER) [expr {$::env(ECO_ITER) + 1}]
            puts "$::env(ECO_ITER)" # This is 0
            
            # Do stuff
        }
    }
    # Exit the loop
    break
}
```

I also tried the following but it did not fix the problem:

```
incr ::env(ECO_ITER) 1
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please develop a _complete_ reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This behaves as expected: `set fh [open /etc/passwd]; set txt [split [read $fh] \n]; set ::env(ECO_ITER) 0; foreach line $txt {incr ::env(ECO_ITER); puts $::env(ECO_ITER)}`

Comment: @glennjackman it seems that I do not have the semicolons at the end of every statement. Would that be a problem? Thanks

Comment: @glennjackman I made some edits to make the problem reproducible. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of relying on an external file, your example could just iterate over a list of values set in the code itself.... Or since it breaks as the last command in the foreach body, and doesn't use the list variable `$line` at all in the body, just `$txt`, not have a loop at all...

Comment: Works with 8.5 on macOS, including the incremented value being passed to subprocesses.

Answer (score 0):

This worked when I tried it with the oldest version of Tcl I've got:

```
% set env(foo) 1
1
% exec sh -c {echo '$foo =' $foo}
$foo = 1
% incr env(foo)
2
% exec sh -c {echo '$foo =' $foo}
$foo = 2
% incr env(foo)
3
% exec sh -c {echo '$foo =' $foo}
$foo = 3
```

*However,* I would not expect updating an environment variable to either:

1. Get shared back with the process that calls the Tcl process, or
2. Get shared with already-executing subprocesses.
3. They're also not shared at all with unrelated processes.

That's because environment variables work (on all POSIX platforms, and also on Windows) by ***copying*** the environment from the parent process to the child process on process creation. (Technically, it's actually in the `execve` system call, but that's a minor detail.)

If you are updating the environment and expecting another process to pick it up, unless that other process is launched from the current process after the environment change, it's not going to work.

---

There are some nuances such as reinitialising environment variables from the registry on Windows, or the trickery that is used to set environment variables in module files, but in both those cases it's not the environment itself that is conveying the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was a stupid error on my end.

I reset the env variable at the caller process so the variable was set to 0 no matter what I tried.

Thanks SO!